# How to Concat a DataFrame with String to a DataFrame with Unicode and normalize datatype

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, unicode

I'm having issues when concatenating two dataframes with different types of strings in Python2. One has normal Py2 strings, the other a unicode string. The concatenation works, but the types inside the numpy arrays internally remain the same (by design I'm sure).

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, MultiIndex
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = DataFrame(data={'data': ['A', 'BBB', 'CC']},
                    index=MultiIndex.from_tuples([(dt(2016, 1, 1), 2),
                                                  (dt(2016, 1, 1), 3),
                                                  (dt(2016, 1, 2), 2)],
                                                 names=['date', 'id']))

df2 = DataFrame(data={'data': [u'AAAAAAA']},
                     index=MultiIndex.from_tuples([(dt(2016, 1, 2), 4)],
                                                  names=['date', 'id']))

df3 = pd.concat([df, df2])
```

output:

```
>>> df.data.values
array(['A', 'BBB', 'CC'], dtype=object)

>>> df2.data.values
array([u'AAAAAAA'], dtype=object)

>>> df3.data.values
array(['A', 'BBB', 'CC', u'AAAAAAA'], dtype=object)
```

As you can see, the array is now 'mixed', it has strings and unicode. Is there a way to force it to typecast to one or the other? If not, is there an easy way to check if one side is unicode or not, and convert that column to str or unicode?

(I care because pd.lib.infer_dtype will mark the dtype of this numpy array as "mixed" and I need it to be marked as either 'string' or 'unicode' to differentiate it from other objects that can also be stored in Pandas/Numpy Arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `applymap` and `encode`

```
df3.applymap(lambda s: s.encode('utf8'))
```

[image]

```
df3.applymap(lambda s: s.encode('utf8')).data.values

array(['A', 'BBB', 'CC', 'AAAAAAA'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 3):

Pandas has an astype method but it returns a series. This will work.

```
    df2_copy = pd.DataFrame(d2.data.astype(str))

    df2_copy.data.values
    array(['AAAAAAA'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Wish I could accept both answers! They both work, but other answer is better for my specific use case. Thanks!